# Using a view to attach fields from a content type to another one

Tags: 7, views

I am a bit new to this, but I do have a programming background, and I have been working with Drupal for a while.

I am putting together a site for our Yoga Studio and I have a content type (scheduled class)  that has a field (field scheduled_class) that is a node reference to a content type (class description). The Scheduled Class content type has as field for date which is used in a calendar, and there are multiple classes using the same class description.

I am trying to use a view to attach fields from the class description to the scheduled class content type and I cannot get it to work. I have been banging my head against the wall for months now.

```
                               --> fields
Scheduled class --> Class Type --> fields   
                               --> fields
```

I have not been able to get the contextual filter and relationship set up properly to allow this to work. I have tried every single combination I can think of. I am pretty sure the source of the problem is trying to get the right default value of the Class Type, but I am not sure.

Comment: Can I please ask you to re-title the question to be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

What I would do:

Enable the query preview under Views settings.

1. Create a new View.
2. Make sure "Title" is a selected field, and that the titles of both "Scheduled classes" and "Class type" is available in the list.
3. Add a new relationship, pick the one representing your node-reference. Make it required.
4. Change the title-fields configuration to select the newly added the relationship.
5. You should now only have titles from "Class type".

From there on, you likely want to add a contextual filter on a nid so you can pick out "Class type" from a specific "Scheduled class".

I haven't used [references](http://drupal.org/project/references) in a while. If you get stuck already here, give the same thing a try with [entity reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) instead, just to see if it plays better together with Views.

Also see [Learn Views with NodeOne](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/taming-the-beast-learn-views-with-nodeone), episode 11 is specifically about relationships.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you.

1. Make a content view.
2. Add a filter for "Content:type" that shows only the node of the "scheduled class" content type.
3. Add the relationship "Content: Field node reference."
4. Add the field "Content:body" and use the above relationship while displaying.